# cannot read mp3 in the jar file. (getResourceAsStream and MediaPlayer)

Tags: multithreading, jar, mp3, javafx-8, executable-jar

When I export project to .jar file, the thread which supposed to play sound cannot start. There have to be some problem within constructor and I'm guessing some problem with loading the mp3 file. However I dont get `URISyntaxException`.

(Everything works fine within eclipse project)
This class exist inside `SpokenNumbersController` class

```
MediaPlayer media[] = new MediaPlayer[10];
private StringBuilder language = new StringBuilder("/PL.");

    public PlayDigits(){
            generatedDigits = new StringBuilder();
            this.thisType = type;


            for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
                StringBuilder directory = new StringBuilder(language.toString());
                switch(i){
                    case 0: directory.append("Zero.mp3");
                        break;
                    case 1: directory.append("One.mp3");
                        break;
                    case 2: directory.append("Two.mp3");
                        break;
                    case 3: directory.append("Three.mp3");
                        break;
                    case 4: directory.append("Four.mp3");
                        break;
                    case 5: directory.append("Five.mp3");
                        break;
                    case 6: directory.append("Six.mp3");
                        break;
                    case 7: directory.append("Seven.mp3");
                        break;
                    case 8: directory.append("Eight.mp3");
                        break;
                    case 9: directory.append("Nine.mp3");
                        break;
                    default: break;     
                }

        //      URL path = getClass().getResource(directory.toString());
//              media[i] = new MediaPlayer(new Media(path.toString()));

                try {
                    media[i] = new MediaPlayer(new Media(Main.class.getResource(directory.toString()).toURI().toString()));
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    Dialogs.create().title("Error").masthead(null).message("Couldn't load the mp3").showError();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            digitsToFinish = (int) Math.round(sliderCountdown.getValue());
        }
```

Here is my files directory:

[image]

I've found that I need to use getResourceAsStream() but how can I do it with MediaPlayer?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution with JLayer...

```
String media[] = new String[10];
...
(its a loop as above)
media[i] = directory.toString();
...

InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(media[iToDigit]);
Player player = new Player(is);

new Thread(new Runnable() { //just to play sound in background not in main thread
    @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                player.play();
            } catch (JavaLayerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
}).start();
```

Now exported jar file also plays sound.